# C# error : Value should be between minimum and maximum

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a I have 2 panels with scrollbars. I am trying to use just one scroll bar to scroll both panels simultaneously. However I get this error :

```
Value of '2268' is not valid for 'value'.'Value' should be between 'minimum' and maximum'
Parameter name: Value.
```

In the scroll event of one of the panels, I have used the following code:

```
     private void panel8_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            panel8.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = panel7.HorizontalScroll.Maximum;
            panel7.HorizontalScroll.Value = panel8.HorizontalScroll.Value;
        }
```

I need the scrollbar on panel8 to control the scrolling of both panel 7 and 8

EDIT: 
panel8 maximum value is 13175 and panel 7 maximum value is 2004.
panel8 HorizontalScroll Value is 2268.
panel7 HorizontalScroll Value is 2268.

Comment: What are the values for ´panel8.HorizontalScroll.Maximum´, ´panel7.HorizontalScroll.Maximum´, ´panel7.HorizontalScroll.Value´ and ´panel8.HorizontalScroll.Value´?

Comment: I guess you have exceeded the maximum value set for the panel, can you post the values ?

Comment: you are stating that the max value for panel7 is 2004 but you are trying to set it to 2268. 2268 > 2004. How should panel 8 controll panel 7? are you looking for a ratio Ie. if panel 8 is in the middle so should panel 7 be?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you wish for the panel 7 to be in the same relative position as panel 8 then do this

```
private void panel8_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    var p8Max = panel8.HorizontalScroll.MaxValue
    var p8Min = panel8.HorizontalScroll.MinValue
    var p7Max = panel7.HorizontalScroll.MaxValue
    var p7Min = panel7.HorizontalScroll.MinValue 
    var ratio = panel8.HorizontalScroll.Value/(p8Max-p8Min)
    var absoluteValue = ratio * (p7Max-p7Min)
    panel7.HorizontalScroll.Value = p7Min + absoluteValue
}
```

Comment: You might want to take the MinValue into account as well. In general it will be 0 but just in case someone adjusts it...

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd good point especially since it's not specified to be zero in this case